# AWS dynamodb with Ruby SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-dynamodb

I have tables in dynamodb. I am new to 'AWS'.now my site is getting very slow. I couldn't find the solution. I suspect DynamoDB. So I need to know some details about DynamoDB. What is Read and write capacity, latency, CPU utilization? How to handle these all? to get DB gets fast?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a table, you specify the provisioned capacity for read and write. This will limit the number of records you can read per second and number of records you can write per second. Your use-case will determine your actual needs. You can modify the provisioned capacity of a table after you have created, while it is being used and it will not affect access. This hot upgrade is a powerful feature of DynamoDB.

If you are exceeding your provisioned capacity, then DynamoDB will throttle your API calls. The `aws-sdk` gem will automatically retry throttled DynamoDB calls up to 10 times, using an exponential backoff strategy, sleeping between attempts.

To configure the retry limit for DynamoDB:

```
Aws.config[:dynamodb] = { retry_limit: 5 }
```

You can tell if your request is getting retried by inspecting the response object:

```
ddb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new
resp = ddb.get_item(table_name: 'aws-sdk', key: { id: '123' })
resp.context.retires
#=> 0
```

Also, you can enable logging:

```
require 'logger'
ddb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(logger: Rails.logger)
ddb.get_item(table_name: 'aws-sdk', key: { id: '123' })

# sent to the rails logger
[Aws::DynamoDB::Client 200 0.008879 0 retries] get_item(table_name:"aws-sdk",key:{"id"=>{s:"123"}})
```

The log message contains the service client call, the HTTP status code (200), the time spent waiting on the call, the number of retires and the operation name and params called. You can of course configure the `:log_level` and a `:log_formatter` to modify when and what things are logged.